# Is Objective-C on Linux garbage collected?

Tags: objective-c, gcc, garbage-collection, g++

Objective-C v2.0 (which is what the mac uses) got a new feature, Garbage Collection. I'm a kid on a Linux PC (Ubuntu in case your wondering). So my question is, using the gcc/g++ compiler is Objective-C Garbage Collected?

Comment: You should revisit this question. My answer is wrong, but I can't delete it because it has been accepted. You should accept the most-upvoted question instead.

Comment: please follow up on mipadi's comment please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replies above are wrong. Garbage collection [has been a part of gcc's implementation of Objective-C since at least gcc 2.95](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/objc-features_1.html#SEC5). The most recent version is gcc 4.4.1.

Answer (score 2):

If you are refereing to Gnustep Objective-C. I think you have to build gnustep with gc enabled and linked to some gc library. But if you do apt-get install it comes built like that.