# Is objective-C garbage collected?

Tags: objective-c

Is objective-C garbage collected?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Objective-C on Linux garbage collected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668576/is-objective-c-on-linux-garbage-collected)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It *can* be, since version 2.0.

(But not on the iPhone.)

Comment: I believe GNUStep has also supported the Boem collector for a while, if you are interested in ObjC on non-Mac OS X based platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use the garbage collection feature if ur planning on writing iOS apps.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why? In an environment where memory is strictly limited (iphone, ipad), it's very practical to have automatic garbage collection.